# create span tag and insert with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to populate a span tag that i was to insert into my page with jquery.

i tried this

```
var span = $('<span />').attr({'className':'folder_name' , 'text':'favre' });
var insert=
$('<div/>', {
    className: "folder",
    html: span
});
```

which yielded this result.

```
<div classname="folder">
<span classname="folder_name" text="favre"></span>
</div>
```

---

then i tried this

```
 var span = $('<span />').attr({'className':'folder_name', 'html':'Elway' });
```

which yielded this

```
 <div classname="folder">
 <span classname="folder_name" html="Elway"></span>
 </div>
```

**what i am trying to get is below**

```
 <div classname="folder">
 <span classname="folder_name" >**Elway**</span>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The HTML of an object is not an attribute and needs to be supplied separately:

```
var span = $('<span />').attr('className', 'folder_name').html('Elway');
```

Also, `className` is not a valid attribute, do you mean `class` instead, if so use this:

```
var span = $('<span />').addClass('folder_name').html('Elway');
```

Comment: awesome good catch on the classnname that was another mistake

Answer (score 11):

I prefer the 'createElement' method of native JS. This is faster than the jQuery method alone

```
var $span = $( document.createElement('span') );
$span.addClass('folder_name').html('Elway');
```

Answer (score 7):

Try with:

```
var span = $('<span />').attr('class', 'folder_name').html('Elway');
```

A [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Bs4K/)

Answer (score 5):

I do not recommend using custom attributes like `className`, I believe it is standard practice to prefix any needed custom attributes with `data-`.  That being said, you can use the jquery method `$.append()` to accomplish your goal.

**Here is a basic example:**

```
var div = $('<div />', { 'className':'folder' })
.append('<span className="folder-name">Elway</span>');

$('body').html(div);
```

Link to jQuery documentation on **append**:

http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 2):

try to append the html at the end

```
var span = $('<span />').attr({'className': 'folder_name'}).html('html here');
```

Suggested By [**Rory McCrossan**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/519413/rory-mccrossan)

if you are using `className` as your own attribute than change it, inventing your own attributes will render the page invalid and lead to other issues. If you need to create your own attribute use `data-*`

but if it is class than change it to `class`

Comment: `if you are using className as your own attribute than it's okay` no it's not, inventing your own attributes will render the page invalid and lead to other issues. If you need to create your own attribute use `data-*`

Comment: added your suggestion in the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var span = $('<span />',{
    className:'folder_name' , 
    html:'Elway' 
});

var insert = $('<div/>', {
    className: "folder",
    html: span
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vcsBP/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You can also create an HTML string and attach it to the target element:

```
var html = '<div class="folder">' +
               '<span class="folder_name">Text</span>' +
           '</div>';

$('body').append(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var customSpan = document.createElement('span');
customSpan.classList.add("notActive");
```